# Redirect after pdf generation

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm generating a pdf after a form submission and I'd like to redirect to a "pdf has been generated" or reload the page with the form. I don't know how to do that, I guess it can be done with javascript/jquery but I didn't found a way to do that.

This is the view that generates the pdf:

```
def myview(response):
    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    result = generate_pdf('my_template.html', file_object=resp)
    return result
```

Comment: I tried the given solutions with no success. The views get redirected without generating the pdf.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect from same view tath you are creating the PDF file, one option is send the success page first, and after start the download.

Your success view:

```
def pdf_success(request):
    # View stuff
    return render_to_response('pdf.html', {}, context_instance=ctx)
```

And you need to add this to your `pdf.html` template:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url={% url "myview" %}">
```

Answer (score 2):

First create that success view:

```
def pdf_success(request):
    return render_to_response('pdf_success.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then do a redirection after success:

```
def myview(response):
    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    result = generate_pdf('my_template.html', file_object=resp)
    if result:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/to/success/view')
```

Just to give you the idea

Answer (score 2):

From this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2103/) you can create a custom decorator

```
 from functools import wraps
 from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, HttpResponseRedirect

def redirect(url):
    """
    Executes a HTTP 302 redirect after the view finishes processing. If a value is 
    returned, it is ignored. Allows for the view url to be callable so the
    reverse() lookup can be used.

    @redirect('http://www.google.com/')
    def goto_google(request):
        pass

    @redirect(lambda: reverse('some_viewname'))
    def do_redirect(request):
        ...

    """
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer




def permanent_redirect(url):
    """
    Executes a HTTP 301 (permanent) redirect after the view finishes processing. If a
    value is returned, it is ignored. Allows for the view url to be callable so the
    reverse() lookup can be used.

    @permanent_redirect('/another-url/')
    def redirect_view(request):
        ...

    @redirect(lambda: reverse('some_viewname'))
    def do_redirect(request):
        ...

    """
    def outer(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url if not callable(url) else url())
        return inner
    return outer
```

You can use any of these from the next way:

```
@redirect('http://stackoverflow.com')
def myview(response):
    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    result = generate_pdf('my_template.html', file_object=resp)
    return result
```

or:

```
    @permanent_redirect('http://stackoverflow.com')
    def myview(response):
        resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        result = generate_pdf('my_template.html', file_object=resp)
        return result
```